# VS 2012 IIS Express 8 - Unable to launch web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

I've created brand new ASP.NET MVC 4 application in VS2012 (Windows 7 64-bit). When I run app using IIS Express 8, my application is not started. Using FireBug I noticed that "site.css" file cannot be delivered, because HTTP GET request is hanging.

I didn't find any requests for these files in the IIS log:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2013-04-12 17:39:15
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken 
2013-04-12 17:39:15 ::1 GET / - 57178 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:20.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/20.0 - 200 0 0 7163 
2013-04-12 17:39:15 ::1 GET /Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js - 57178 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:20.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/20.0 http://localhost:57178/ 304 0 0 2 
2013-04-12 17:39:15 ::1 GET /favicon.ico - 57178 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:20.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/20.0 - 304 0 0 14 
2013-04-12 17:39:39 ::1 GET / - 57178 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:20.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/20.0 - 200 0 0 5
```

BTW, on the Visual Studio Development Server the app is working perfectly.
Will appreciate any ideas and help.